# How do I remove/ replace these bulbs

Tags: light

There is a spring type bracket holding the bulb in place but I cannot remove the cover plate or the can [image][image][image]

Comment: Did you try unscrewing the trim around the bulb?

Comment: try using  a suction cup on the face of the bulb and just unscrew them.  That spring is likely used to allow the bulb housing to rotate to certain angles in the large housing.  HD and B&B sell special bulb suction for this purpose.  Also keep the ring from rotating while unscrewing the bulb.  Position the buld like the second picture to hold the ring.

Answer (score 1):

It's a PAR20 pot light. It is a screw-in bulb.

The spring you can see is holding part of the trim onto the bulb, not holding the bulb in place.

You need to gently pull the full unit out, including all of the trim, in order to get access to the bulb. It is held lightly by spring-loaded clips. Once you get it started, inspect how it is held in. Some have retractable springs which will allow you to pull it fully out, others will have clips that need to be separated.

As others have mentioned you need to free the trim from the paint before attempting to remove it, or you may end up pulling off more ceiling paint than you intended.

Answer (score 0):

The entire faceplate pulls down about an inch and is attached with clips that can then be released, removing the whole unit. The bulb can then be unscrewed and removed.

As the trim has been painted and is sealed to the ceiling, you may have to run a razor around the edge to sever the paint, then try gently prying the plate down.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a pot light.  The gimble and trim kit should pull out of the pot light housing leaving the bulb.  The pictures make it look like someone painted the trim kit with the ceiling so you might have to cut around the sides where the trim kit meets the ceiling in order to pull the trim kit down from the potlight.

Answer (score 0):

I have these lights, you have to pull the whole trim kit off. It is the largest diameter circle in your pictures. Once you separate this from the ceiling, the trim with gimbal and bulb will come out together - connected to the rest of the can only by the two power wires. Now you will be able to see how to pry the bulb out from the gimbal where it is held in by the 2 spring clips.

Your bulbs may have a screw in base, or may be GU10. You may want to disconnect the bulb from the socket first, so you can bring the unit to a more comfortable position before prying the bulb from the gimbal.